# An error occurred (EntityTooSmall) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation: Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have the following code for uploading s3 using MultipartUpload.

```
import logging
import boto3


class UploadS3:
    def __init__(self, bucket, prefix):
        self.s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        self.bucket = bucket
        self.prefix = prefix

    def start(self, key):
        '''Start to upload a new file'''
        self.part_no = 1
        self.parts = []
        key_path = f'{self.prefix}/{key}'
        self.s3obj = self.s3.Object(self.bucket, key_path)
        self.mpu = self.s3obj.initiate_multipart_upload()
        self.buffer = bytearray()

    def upload(self, chunk):
        '''Upload a chunk'''
        if len(self.buffer) >= 5_000_000:
            self._upload_buffer()
        self.buffer += chunk

    def end(self, part_info={}):
        if len(self.buffer):
            self._upload_buffer()
        part_info['Parts'] = self.parts
        mpu_result = self.mpu.complete(MultipartUpload=part_info)
        logging.info(f'Upload result: {mpu_result}')

    def _upload_buffer(self):
        self.part = self.mpu.Part(self.part_no)
        print(f'buffer len: {len(self.buffer)}')
        resp = self.part.upload(Body=self.buffer)
        print({'PartNumber': self.part_no, 'ETag': resp['ETag']})
        self.parts.append({'PartNumber': self.part_no, 'ETag': resp['ETag']})
        self.part_no += 1
        self.buffer = bytearray()
```

And I created the following test code:

```
upload_s3 = UploadS3(BUCKET, PREFIX)
key = 'key2'
upload_s3.start(key)
upload_s3.upload(b'0' * 1_000_000)
upload_s3.upload(b'1' * 1_000_000)
upload_s3.upload(b'2' * 1_000_000)
upload_s3.upload(b'3' * 1_000_000)
upload_s3.upload(b'4' * 999_999)
upload_s3.upload(b'abcde')
upload_s3.upload(b'12345')
upload_s3.end({})
```

However, it got the following error. The length of the first part is 5000004 and the second (**last**) part is 5, which doesn't need to be over 5M?

```
buffer len: 5000004
{'PartNumber': 1, 'ETag': '"e616f253def9510e3be2af0854e4c992"'}
buffer len: 5
{'PartNumber': 2, 'ETag': '"db44331bface5c8678770426baf73bc2"'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "test1.py", line 31, in main
    upload_s3.end({})
  File "/home/x/upload_s3.py", line 31, in end
    mpu_result = self.mpu.complete(MultipartUpload=part_info)
  File "/apps/external/4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/apps/external/4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/apps/external/4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/apps/external/4/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (EntityTooSmall) when calling the CompleteMultipartUpload operation: Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of writing this answer, the [S3 multipart upload limitations page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html) has the following table:

| Item | Specification |
| --- | --- |
| Maximum object size | 5 TB |
| Maximum number of parts per upload | 10,000 |
| Part numbers | 1 to 10,000 (inclusive) |
| **Part size** | **5 MB to 5 GB. There is no minimum size limit on the last part of your multipart upload.** |
| Maximum number of parts returned for a list parts request | 1000 |
| Maximum number of multipart uploads returned in a list multipart uploads request | 1000 |

**However**, there is a subtle mistake. It says 5 MB instead of 5 MiB (and possibly 5 GB should actually be 5 GiB).

Since you split the parts every `5 000 000` bytes (which are 5 MB but "only" ~4.77 MiB) both the first and second parts are smaller than the minimum size.

You should instead split the parts every `5 242 880` (`5 * 1024 ** 2`) bytes (or even a bit [no pun intended] more just to be on the safe side).

I submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-s3-userguide/pull/53) on the S3 docs page.

Comment: Hi despite trying with various different chunks sizes ranging from 5*1024*1024 to 15*1024*1024 I am still receiving this error.. I am using js to upload the parts from cli and then a python rest to completeMultipartFormUpload.. am I missing something?